# Compare and swap with SIMD intrinsics

Tags: c++, simd

Is it possible to compare in SIMD instruction and swap the values if some condition happened. In other words, I have 4 integers:

```
(100 5) (1 42)
```

And I want to receive:

```
(5 100) (1 42)
```

i.e. I want to compare pairwise (first value with second and third with fourth) and in case left operand is greater - swap the values. Is it possible to do with only 1 SIMD?

P.S.: it's the first time I'm trying SIMD and probably I'm using wrong terminology - please fix me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Whats wrong with the "obvious approach" that you're looking into SIMD (or wtv else) ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot to mention what I'm doing this for learning purposes. I'm trying to implement different sorting algorithms and speed it up as much as I can.

Comment: ir's so hard to talk about SIMD without knowing which set of SIMD to talk about, like, SSE/AVX or something else?

Comment: I don't know - is there any way to check it with visual studio? I know that I have Intel Core i7 4930K - and it seems it supports AVX, but I don't know which version.

Comment: @nikitablack AVX(1) (so, not 2) because it's an Ivy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want to sort pairs of 32-bit integers in a single XMM register. There is no ready instruction for it of course, but you can do it in a few instructions with SSE4.1 (*beware:* code not tested):

```cpp
//input = [100, 5, 1, 42]
__m128i swapped = _mm_shuffle_epi32(input, _MM_SHUFFLE(2,3,0,1)); // [5, 100, 42, 1]
__m128i comp = _mm_cmplt_epi32(input, swapped);                   // [0, -1, -1, 0]
comp = _mm_xor_si128(comp, _mm_set_epi32(-1, 0, -1, 0));          // [0, 0, -1, -1]
input = _mm_blendv_epi8(swapped, input, comp);                    // [5, 100, 1, 42]
```

It seems to be 7 uops and take 2 CPU cycles (throughput) on Ivy Bridge.

It can be easily ported to AVX2 if wanted.

Comment: @nikitablack: Go to Intel Intrinsics Guide and check each command one by one. it is not so hard to understand. BTW xor instruction can be replaced with another shuffle.

Comment: Thanks, already did. And can you give a hint how to replace xor with a shuffle - I can't figure it myself. How do I know which elements to shuffle?

Comment: @nikitablack: Comparison produces four 32-bit masks as a result. However, the first and the second results must be complement: *(a < b) != (b < a)*   (unless *a == b*, in which case any mask suits). The same is true for the third and the fourth results.
Right now I invert the second and the fourth masks, but you can instead copy first mask to the second one, and the third mask to the fourth. This in-register copying of elements can be done with a single call of `_mm_shuffle_epi32`.

Answer (score 6):

For AVX2 capable systems there is a solution using min/max and blend with `imm` (which has 1 cycle latency vs. 2 cycles for variable one).

Following code has 3 cycles latency and should have less than 2cycles throughput on HSW+

```
__m128i tmp = _mm_shuffle_epi32(in, _MM_SHUFFLE(2,3,0,1));
__m128i min = _mm_min_epi32(in, tmp);
__m128i max = _mm_max_epi32(in, tmp);
// __m128i res = _mm_blend_epi32(min, max, 0xA); // AVX2 only
__m128i res = _mm_blend_epi16(min, max, 0xCC);   // SSE4.1
```

I've tested it on my HSW system (processing 20000 pairs 100K times) and it has ~26% better performance than the code by `stgatilov`

```
CMP + VARIABLE BLEND    1.18sec
MIN/MAX + BLEND_32      0.87sec // AVX2 only code
MIN/MAX + BLEND_PS      0.86sec // SSE
MIN/MAX + PLEND_16      0.88sec // Preferred for SSE
```

**UPDATE**: Per `stgatilov`' comment below.  All MIN/MAX implementations have virtually the same performance (most likely just stuck into memory b/w)

Comment: Yes, using min/max provides a much simpler solution. I think this solution can be adapted to SSE4.1. Just use `_mm_blend_epi16` or `_mm_blend_ps` instead of `_mm_blend_epi32` (some latency/throughput penalty may be possible).

Comment: @Elalfer Thank you. Can you please explain what is **cycle latency** means? Nad what is **HSW+**?

Comment: @nikitablack **Instruction latency** - how many cycles it takes to execute a single instruction, **HSW+** - is Haswell microarchitecture and beyond (Broadwell, Skylake). You can find more information on instructions latency and throughput @ https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/